# How to focus inputfields while click on 'Tab' button in unity 3d

Tags: unity-game-engine

[image]I want focus input fields using tab button. I have found some code for focusing input fields but that one not satisfied my requirement. In my application one page design like number of input field in both horizontal and vertical formate. In my page have 3 rows of input field and each row have 3 input fields. my requirement is when user click on tab button focus next input field it's working but when reach end of the row, how can I focus next row contain input field. Please suggest any idea. Thank you. You can find my sample page design in below.

Here is the code I have tried.

```
Selectable next = system.currentSelectedGameObject.GetComponent<Selectable().FindSelectableOnRight();                               
if (next != null)
{
    InputField inputfield = next.GetComponent<InputField>();

    if (inputfield != null)
    {                       
        inputfield.OnPointerClick(new PointerEventData(system)); 
        system.SetSelectedGameObject(next.gameObject, new BaseEventData(system));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had implemented the a similar function by NGUI, you can make some modify if using UGUI. The idea is set the nextInput manually by public variable

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class UIInputTab : MonoBehaviour {

    UIInput thisInput;
    public GameObject nextInput;
    void Start () {
        thisInput = transform.GetComponent<UIInput>();
    }

    void Update () {
        if (thisInput.isSelected)
        {
            if (nextInput != null && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Tab))
            {
                UICamera.selectedObject = nextInput;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Update**

: Dynamic generate random number InputField and assign the next InputField.

InputfieldTest.cs

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class InputfieldTest : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject inputFieldPrefab;
    public GameObject panel;
    private GameObject lastInput;

    EventSystem m_EventSystem;

    void Start () {

        m_EventSystem = EventSystem.current;

        for(int i = 0; i < Random.Range(5,10);i++){
            GameObject column = new GameObject();
            column.transform.parent = panel.transform;
            column.name = "Column" + i;

            for (int j = 0; j < Random.Range(2, 8);j++){
                GameObject input = Instantiate(inputFieldPrefab);
                input.transform.parent = column.transform;
                input.GetComponent<RectTransform>().position = new Vector3(300+ 200 * j, 300+ 200 * i, 0);
                input.name = "InputField" + i + "-" + j;

                // set nextInput
                if(lastInput != null) {
                    lastInput.GetComponent<InputTabControl>().nextInput = input;
                }

                lastInput = input;
            }
        }
    }

    void Update () {
        GameObject currentSelect = m_EventSystem.currentSelectedGameObject;

        if (currentSelect != null)
        {
            print(currentSelect.name);
            GameObject nextInput = currentSelect.GetComponent<InputTabControl>().nextInput;
            if (nextInput != null && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Tab))
            {
                InputField inputfield = nextInput.GetComponent<InputField>();

                if (inputfield != null)
                {
                    inputfield.OnPointerClick(new PointerEventData(m_EventSystem));
                    m_EventSystem.SetSelectedGameObject(nextInput.gameObject, new BaseEventData(m_EventSystem));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

InputTabControl.cs

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class InputTabControl : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject nextInput;

}
```

Result:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response. Above code seems to go to next input field in the bottom but my page have input fields present in both horizontal and vertical manner. I have update my question with image. There you can get the my page design contain input fields pattern.

Comment: Hi, In my design each column generated dynamically. We don't know how many columns. So how can we able to assign next input field manually.

Comment: Thank you very much siusiulala. Above process working fine for me.

Answer (score 2):

Here's my solution, pretty similar.

```
public class TabToNextController : MonoBehaviour {

    public InputField nextField;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        if (GetComponent<InputField> ().isFocused && Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.Tab)) {
            nextField.ActivateInputField ();
        }
}
```

Just add this script to the item you want to be tabbed from. Then in the GUI drop in the inputfield you want to be tabbed to as the "nextField".

Comment: This should be the best solution. Clean and simple.

Comment: Calling GetComponent() in each Update() may be quite cpu intensive, better cache it.

Comment: ActivateInputField() is broken in all versions of Unity up to at least 2021 - in theory this should work, but until Unity's engineers resume fixing bugs (they appear to have a corporate policy now to "not fix UI because too many people are still using it, instead of using the even more broken UIToolkit we want them to use instead") this isn't stable, only works sometimes, in some cases.

Answer (score 1):

I recently ran into this problem and it drove me crazy to think there was no tabs feature. I had never noticed it before. A simple solution that seems to work so far is to use the `Selectable` class that the UI elements inherit from.

I tested this with the most common types (for me) - InputField, Buttons and drop down lists.

- It *tabs* to each of them as expected
- use spacebar to click the button
- use spacebar to open the drop down

If you want full web style controls (eg arrow keys) to invoke the drop down, you need to write that code.

```
public class TabToNextController : MonoBehaviour, IUpdateSelectedHandler
{
    public Selectable nextField;

    public void OnUpdateSelected(BaseEventData data)
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Tab))
            nextField.Select();
    }
}
```

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me:

```
    public Selectable next; //if you want the cursor to start at a specific field
                            //you can set this in the inspector to any input field
    private EventSystem system;
    private int tabIndex; //to keep track of cursor
    void Start()
    {
        system = EventSystem.current;// EventSystemManager.currentSystem;
        //if you don't want to set next in the inspector, you can do it here
        //next = Selectable.allSelectables[0];
        tabIndex = 0;
        next.Select(); //make sure to do this!
    }
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Tab))
        {
            if (tabIndex >= Selectable.allSelectables.Count) 
            {
                next = Selectable.allSelectables[0];
                tabIndex = 0;
            } 
            else 
            {
        //if nothing is selected then system.currentSelectedGameObject 
        //will throw a nullPointer Exception
                next = system.currentSelectedGameObject.GetComponent<Selectable>()
                       .FindSelectableOnDown(); 
                tabIndex++;
            }
            Debug.Log(next);
            if (next != null)
            {
             
                InputField inputfield = next.GetComponent<InputField>();
                if (inputfield != null)
                    inputfield.OnPointerClick(new PointerEventData(system));  //if it's an input field, also set the text caret
             
                system.SetSelectedGameObject(next.gameObject, new BaseEventData(system));
            }
        }
    }
```